# DAX - calculate the % likelihood of a person who has "A" with the chances the person has "B" as well

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a requirement where I have two columns like this.

```
ID     Disease-Type
1       A
1       D
1       A
2       B
2       B
2       A
2       C
3       D
3       D
```

And Now I want to select a disease from Disease-Type. Lets say "A".

I want to see in the graph like this,

```
B    100%
C    100%
D    50%
```

B is 100% because if that id has disease B then also had Disease "A" (the selected disease). C is 100% because if that id had disease C then also had Disease "A" (the selected disease).

while D is ionly 50%, because out of 2 Unique ID's (1, 3) which had "D" only 1 has Disease Type "A".

Also to note, A shouldn't be seen in the output visual. which will be plotted against Disease-Type.

How can I use DAX to do this. Please explain me with VAR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want a disconnected table to use as a slicer to select A/B/C/D. You can create a calculated table like this

```
Disease = VALUES ( Table1[Disease-Type] )
```

Now you need a measure which reads your slicer selection and computes the desired percentages.

```
Percent =
VAR SelectedType =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Disease[Disease-Type] )
VAR SelectedIDs =
    CALCULATETABLE ( VALUES ( Table1[ID] ), Table1[Disease-Type] = SelectedType )
VAR CurrentIDs = 
    VALUES ( Table1[ID] )
RETURN
    DIVIDE (
        COUNTROWS ( INTERSECT ( SelectedIDs, CurrentIDs ) ),
        COUNTROWS ( CurrentIDs )
    )
```

The first variable `SelectedType` reads in your slicer selection and the second variable `SelectedIDs` is a list of `ID` values associated with that type (for selection `A` this is the set `{1, 2}`). The third variable `CurrentIDs` is a list of `ID` values in the current evaluation context (e.g. on the row/column of a matrix visual). For `D`, this set is `{1, 3}`.

Finally, you take the count of the intersection divided by the count of `CurrentIDs` to get your percentage. For the row/column with `D`, this would be

```
|{1}| / |{1, 3}| = 1 / 2 = 50%
```

Comment: can you help me with this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66388855/dax-measure-to-calculate-average-with-parameters-inside-it